# How to delete broken commits in git that has commit id but not readable

Tags: git

I have a repo that when I run `git fsck --full`, I got a long list of broken commit ids:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (861/861), done.
error: Could not read 0f514378e088c610cbeb8b047c63d4209736d1f9
failed to parse commit 0f514378e088c610cbeb8b047c63d4209736d1f9 from object database for commit-graph
error: Could not read 1e77fe5a6c4bec9bc9bd7ac5c00f2bbe98249b44
failed to parse commit 1e77fe5a6c4bec9bc9bd7ac5c00f2bbe98249b44 from object database for commit-graph
error: Could not read 2a86db8a8c83ac0fdb5050efa63b518fbeaf8146
failed to parse commit 2a86db8a8c83ac0fdb5050efa63b518fbeaf8146 from object database for commit-graph
error: Could not read 2d898d27a8858cfba7db93f79ada3bdca181758d
failed to parse commit 2d898d27a8858cfba7db93f79ada3bdca181758d from object database for commit-graph
...
error: Could not read fc80facb8f8bf3a5972c51b2e9ae5e63552db2f0
failed to parse commit fc80facb8f8bf3a5972c51b2e9ae5e63552db2f0 from object database for commit-graph
Verifying commits in commit graph: 100% (28/28), done.
```

I just could not figure out how to delete them. I tried `git gc`, `git prune`, none of them works...

also I have a commit that can be shown as diff with `git show <commit_id>`, but when I run `git branch --contains <commit_id>` , no branch is found, so I believe that is a dangling commit, but again, I tried everything I found on google. None works.

The commands I tried.

```
git prune --expire now
git gc --prune=now
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all"
...
```

Comment: For the commit you mention at the end, it could be reachable from no local branch, but be tagged, or be in the ancestry of a tagged commit, or even on a remote-tracking branch that you never checked out locally. In all these cases, your `git branch --contains <hash>` would not find it. Try adding `-a` to include commits reachable from remote-tracking branches.

Comment: @RomainValeri `git branch -a --contains <hash>` returns nothing too...

Comment: These objects may not be reachable at all: the error occurs while trying to build the commit graph, during the process of painfully iterating over every object *in* the database to see *whether* they're reachable. The objects themselves are corrupted or missing. But as long as they're not actually *used*, that would be OK. Is this a partial clone?

Comment: @torek it is not a partial clone, it does not matter, just that i am having little bit OCD

Comment: Well, might be a good idea to make a backup clone of this clone "just in case" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after changing history with git-repo-filter.
Fixed this with the following command:

```
git commit-graph write --reachable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this with the following command:

```
docker exec -t GitLab git -C /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/30/48/3148905660916d5dde3add79e63f095af3ffb81604691f21cad442a85c7be617.git commit-graph write
```

I use the Docker Omnibus version so your command might vary a bit.
In the path after @hashed, you can find your repo path in the admin section of the GitLab project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Turned out that somehow I had two temp files ".tmp-xxxx-pack-xxxxxxxx..." lurking about in the .git/objects/pack directory.
Try this at your own risk (I'd backup your entire source tree first TBH), but I deleted these .tmp-... files and retried git fsck - it worked perfectly.